# Alexa to BOT QnA maker

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit, direct-line-botframework, azure-qna-maker

We have created a Bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework (C#/.NET SDK) and connected a QnA maker service to the bot.  I want to reuse the same QnA API in my Alexa Skill set (either by Lamda function or using the http request).

[QnAMaker](http://qnamaker.ai/Home/MyServices)

I am trying to create a API controller method as a wrapper class to convert an Alexa intent into a Microsoft intent and vice versa.

```
 public class AlexaController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DirectlineClient _client;

    public AlexaController()
    {
        var directLineSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["directlinesecret"];
        _client = new DirectlineClient(directLineSecret, "alexa" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please precise what do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

We achieved this using an azure function to simply unwrap the Alexa request, massage it into a botframework friendly dto and then use direct line to pass into the botframework. Works a treat

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar. Do you have reference code somewhere?